# Android DefaultHttpClient Cookies with comma in the value

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient

I'm trying to use the DefaultHttpClient in an Android app I've had for sometime. The server I've been authenticating through recently changed some of their stuff and so it broke my app. I've been trying to figure out why, and I think it's related to their having commas in a cookie value they send me; the sysadmin I'm working with was able to show me a value I should have had and I saw the value my app is getting by printing the cookies out to the log. What he sent me:

Cookie: LastMRH_Session=f9d0e6b4; MRHSession=2ab4fe11c9258eb12ebe60d6f9d0e6b4; F5_ST=1,1,1,1346792510,604800; ...

What I got in my logs was just F5_ST and 1 when I printed name and value.

Has anyone run into this before or have an idea of what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well didnt fix the problem I was having, but I got the entire cookie to be used right by:

```
params.setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.NETSCAPE);
```

not sure the implications for the rest of my connections, but it seems to give me the whole cookie back now at least.